# CSS png sprite tester

Tags: php, css

I have this code i have done, it is to test png strips it shows it animated, but it is only working for 1 png strip i have, any others i try it dont work, here is the code below
having rouble puting the code in, here is a link to a pastebin with the code
http://pastebin.com/rXUj9X5W to see what i mean you can test this out at http://xatwebs.co/test.php try using this image to know what i mean www.xatwebs.co/test.png and this image dont work along with others www.imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/6570x30q90/538/zyzaE7.png
code:

```
<?php error_reporting(0); 
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 ?>
<center><p>Test</p></center>
<center><form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Image: <input type="text" name="image" size="5">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form></center>
<?php
}
?>
<?php

$image = $_GET['image'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize(''.$image.'');
if ($image == null) {
die("<center>Enter an image..</center>");
}

else {
$css = '
<style type="text/css">
.hi {
background-image:url("'.$image.'");
width:30px;
height:30px;
margin:auto;
-webkit-animation: hi .8s steps(10) infinite;
-moz-animation: hi .8s steps(10) infinite;
-ms-animation: hi .8s steps(10) infinite;
-o-animation: hi .8s steps(10) infinite;
animation: hi .8s steps(10) infinite;
}
-webkit-keyframes hi {  
from { background-position: 0px; } 
to { background-position: -'.$width.'px; } 
}
@-moz-keyframes hi {  
from { background-position: 0px; } 
to { background-position: -'.$width.'px; } 
} 
@-ms-keyframes hi {  
from { background-position: 0px; } 
to { background-position: -'.$width.'px; }  
}
@-o-keyframes hi {  
from { background-position: 0px; } 
to { background-position: -'.$width.'px; }  
} 
@keyframes hi {  
from { background-position: 0px; } 
to { background-position: -'.$width.'px; } 
}
</style>
';
    echo ''.$css.'<br><img src='.$image.' /><br><div class="hi"></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you open the dev console in the browser to see whether there were errors? For instance, I'm pretty sure imageshack is sensible enough to forbid inlining, so trying to grab that URL as a spritesheet would most likely get stopped by the browser being told it's not allowed to

Comment: I just added the image from imageshack to my site and have same issue :( http://xatwebs.co/test2.jpg

Comment: Please include the code in the question it self. Use the `{}` button to format the code.